# Python dataclasses circular parsing with marshmallow

Tags: python, marshmallow, python-dataclasses

I'm working with a JSON data structure and am trying to represent it as a dataclass. The data structure is (partly) circular and I want the nested data structures to be neatly represented as dataclasses as well.

I am having some trouble getting the dataclasses to parse correctly. See the simplified example below:

```py
from typing import List, Optional, Union


class SchemaTypeName(Enum):
    LONG = "long"
    NULL = "null",
    RECORD = "record"
    STRING = "string"


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class SchemaType():

    type: Union[
        SchemaTypeName,
        'SchemaType',
        List[
            Union[
                SchemaTypeName,
                'SchemaType'
            ]
        ]
    ]

    fields: Optional[List['SchemaType']] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
```

Below is a printout of the object returned after calling `from_dict` with some sample data. Notice that the nested object (indicated with the arrow) is not parsed as a dataclass correctly.

```py
SchemaType(
    type=[
        'null', 
------> {
            'fields': [
                {'name': 'id', 'type': 'string'}, 
                {'name': 'date', 'type': ['null', 'long']}, 
                {'name': 'name', 'type': ['null', 'string']}
            ],
            'type': 'record'
        }
    ]
)
```

Am I declaring the type hint for the `type` field incorrectly?

I'm using `Python 3.9` with `dataclasses_json==0.5.2` and `marshmallow==3.11.1`.

Comment: Hmm, you have a few assumptions wrong with how the dataclass-json library works: 1) The constructor or `__init__` method isn't automatically replaced, so validation and data transformation won't work that way normally. My undestanding is you will need to use helper methods like `from_dict` instead. 2) You don't need to use both `@dataclass_json` decorator and the `DataClassJsonMixin` subclass; using both is redundant, at least from what I understand.

Comment: Correct, I use `from_dict` in the unit test that produced the printout I included in the question. I use the decorator to pass some additional parameters that I left out of the example. The `DataClassJsonMixin` helps `mypy` to pick up on the extra methods such as `from_dict`, it doesn't pick up on those with just the decorator.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I have clarified the question accordingly.

Comment: Hmm, are you certain that the outermost encountered value for `type` will always be a SchemaType or SchemaTypeName, and that all subsequent values for it (for ex. nested within `fields`) will only be a SchemaTypeName? If so, there might be a simple solution for it.

Comment: Within `fields` can be only be a list of `SchemaType` objects. Within `type` can exist a `SchemaTypeName`, `SchemeType`, or a `List` where both types can be mixed. I think this mix is causing difficulty during the parsing step.

Comment: Right, but what i'm asking is if with the specific data you're working with, whether any inner `type` values are a `SchemaType` or a list of `SchemaType`; depending on that, you could probably model your data a bit slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the problem was related to `dataclasses_json` not decoding my elements correctly when they are in a list. Having mixed types in a list causes the decoder to return a list of basic `string`s and `dict`s, without transforming them to instances of `SchemaType` and `SchemaTypeName`.

However, `dataclasses_json` allows you to configure a custom decoder function for any particular field. This is done by importing the `config` function from `dataclasses_json` and providing it as the `metadata` keyword argument for `field`. Next, include the decoder function as the `decoder` keyword argument for `config`.

Please see the updated example below. Using the `schemaTypeDecoder` function, I am able to transform my data to the correct types.

```py
from dataclasses import field
from dataclasses_json import config

class SchemaTypeName(Enum):
    ARRAY = "array"
    LONG = "long"
    NULL = "null"
    OBJECT = "object"
    RECORD = "record"
    STRING = "string"


def schemaTypeDecoder(data: Union[str, dict, List[Union[str, dict]]]):

    def transform(schemaType: Union[str, dict]):
        if isinstance(schemaType, str):
            return SchemaTypeName(schemaType)
        else:
            return SchemaType.from_dict(schemaType)

    if isinstance(data, list):
        return [transform(schemaType) for schemaType in data]
    else:
        return transform(data)


@dataclass_json()
@dataclass
class SchemaType():
    type: Union[
        SchemaTypeName,
        'SchemaType',
        List[
            Union[
                SchemaTypeName,
                'SchemaType'
            ]
        ]
    ] = field(
        metadata=config(
            decoder=schemaTypeDecoder
        )
    )

    fields: Optional[List['SchemaType']] = None
    name: Optional[str] = None
```